# Why does the Prime Meridian line shift in Google Earth when panning?

Tags: geography

I'm not asking about the history of the line, nor am I asking about the tectonic plates underneath. If you look at the gif below, you will see that when panning very close to the earth on Google Earth, the Prime Meridian line (in yellow) seems to shift depending on where you pan. Is this a flaw in Google Earth? I would assume that the line should stay in place, like the other longitude lines.

What am I missing?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ5P4.jpg

PS. Not sure if this is the correct stack exchange site for this question. Please comment if there is a better site.

Comment: Try https://webapps.stackexchange.com as it certainly appears to be a software issue.  I was able to recreate it: https://earth.google.com/web/@51.47388906,0.00365387,44.00379718a,2420.29522507d,35y,2.3628008h,3.14857845t,0r, so it's definitely on the experimental web app. If it's on the desktop version also (if they have it still?), then it might not fit webapps, but not sure where it'd fit :-/ (always helps to provide more directions of where you're looking and what platform you're on when seeing issues!) But not sure anyone on ESE will be able to help. A mod can move the question for you :)

Comment: Can't confirm using GE Pro 7.3.3 under Win10.

Comment: I tried the desktop version, Google Earth Pro, and the meridian appears stationary and in the 'right' place, so it does seem a software issue - maybe related to drawing the prime meridian on the reference ellipsoid, rather than draping it on terrain? It seems to happen with the tropics and the equator as well.

Comment: @AndyM How about in mountains, eg Pyrenees ?

Comment: I looked at the meridian where it crosses the Pyrenees and it seems the same. It is 'draped' on the terrain, but it moves as if it is sitting below surface. But It also does the same out in the Atlantic. I think it is perspective - I looked at the Tropic of Cancer in India and where it crosses the Marianas trench - it behaves as if it is blow India and above the trench, which would fit if it was drawn on a reference ellipsoid.